# Error al compilar una app en android para que lo muestre en la maquina virtual

Tags: android

Hola estoy siguiendo un curso de android y me ha salido este error al momento de probar mi primer trabajo:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Lo he probado con Genymotion y va relativamente bien, solo que hay una caracteristica que no la ejecuta, por ejemplo que aparezca el teclado al presionar sobre un Plain Text, por ello recurro a la maquina virtual de android (mas lenta) y me lanza ese error.

Imagino que se debe aun problema de memoria, ya que solo cuento 8GB de Ram y tener abierto el android Studio mas la maquina virtual y demas las paginas abiertas del navegador donde sigo el curso, incluyendo tambien el mismo sistema operativo W10 no debe ser suficiente para correrlo de la mejor manera.

Intente probando limpiando el proyecto pero aun asi no funciono.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta y agregar el `build.gradle`?

Comment: ¿Qué librerías estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Se determina que debes habilitar el soporte multidex dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` :

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        // Habilita soporte multidex.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Es un problema similar a este thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Comment: ¿No conviene ver el motivo antes de sacar el límite de 64K?

Comment: El motivo es precisamente: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug" ⛔️

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, pero el problema real de mi pc es que no es compatible con Android ya que poseo un procesador AMD fx-6300 lo cual queda corto al compilar la app de prueba y ejecutarla con el emulador de android, llega incluso a ocupar todo el procesador, ademas de toda la memoria RAM por lo que me presentara siempre un error al tratar de ejecutarla...

Como he descubierto como activar el teclado del dispositivo virtual de Genymotion, ya que ese dispositivo virtual funciona igual que uno fisico y solo debia entrar a configuracion y activar la opcion correspondiente, claro que lo debo hacer siempre que se ejecute nuevamente el emulador. Esta pregunta quedaria resuelta...

Solo utilizare el emuladorde Genymotion...